# Convert LocalDateTime to LocalDateTime with specific Zone in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I need to do a `LocalDateTime` conversion of a UTC date to another `LocalDateTime` variable considering a specific timezone tz.

During my research I found many solutions, but they all convert the `LocalDateTime` to another type, like `ZonedDateTime`.

I need something like that, but `LocalDateTime` wont work with `ZoneId`:

`LocalDateTime output = input.getInitDate().of(ZoneId.of(tz))`

Considering a -3 timezone:

```
    input: 2019-12-03T18:24:07

    output: 2019-12-03T15:24:07
```

Comment: "_but they all convert the LocalDateTime to another type, like ZonedDateTime_" – what's wrong with that? LocalDateTime → ZonedDateTime (UTC) → ZonedDateTime (new zone) → LocalDateTime

Comment: Nothing against it, I just thought I could do this conversion directly. There is no way?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` purposely has no concept of time zones, unlike `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: What exactly is returned by `input.getInitDate()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert it first to `ZonedDateTime`, change the timezone, and then extract `LocalDateTime` from that:

```
ZoneId from = ...;
ZoneId to = ...;
LocalDateTime input = ...;
LocalDateTime output = input.atZone(from).withZoneSameInstant(to).toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your Question makes no sense.

You need to understand that [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) holds nothing but a date and a time-of-day. The class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment. The name can be misleading, as a `LocalDateTime` is *not* about any particular locality.

If you want to track a moment in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC. Always in UTC, by definition.
```

If you want to track a moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montevideo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

> LocalDateTime conversion of a UTC date

Do you mean you have particular date and time in mind as seen at the prime meridian? Or as seen in [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland) which uses [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as their time zone?

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ;  // 3 PM.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

This `ldt` object means "3 PM on the 23rd of January this year" *somewhere*, or *anywhere*. But **that `LocalDateTime` object does *not* 3 PM in one particular place**. We have no idea if the intention here is 3 PM in Tokyo Japan or 3 PM in Toulouse France or 3 PM in Toledo Ohio US. Those would be three different moments, several hours apart. A `LocalDateTime` represents *none* of them, or *all* of them, whichever way you want to see it, but not any one of them.

To determine a moment from a date and a time-of-day, you need the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. In other words the third piece of information, in addition to the date and the time-of-day, we need is "as seen in Paris France" or "as seen in [Palmer Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmer_Station) in Antarctica". With such a context, we get either `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, respectively.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Antarctica/Palmer" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ldt , z ) ;  // Giving context of time zone to the date-with-time `LocalDateTime` object. Determines a moment.
```

To see that same moment in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC.
```

## Time zone versus offset-from-UTC

> Considering a -3 timezone:

No, `-3` is *not* a time zone, it is an offset.

The `-3` is short for `-03:00`. Practically speaking, I suggest you avoid abbreviating the offset as some libraries expect a full hours-with-minutes including the colon character, and including the leading zero on single-digit hours or minutes.

The `-3` or `-03:00` means simply "three hours behind UTC".

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone has a name in the form of `Continent/Region` such as `Africa/Tunis` or `Europe/Paris`.

See the [list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on Wikipedia. Sort by offset column. Notice how around three dozen time zones may today be sharing the offset of `-03:00` such as `America/Montevideo`, `Atlantic/Stanley`, and `Antarctica/Palmer`.

Always prefer a time zone to a mere offset. When doing date-time math and adding/subracting spans of time, the results may vary by time zone. Time zones may be using different offsets other than `-03:00` on other dates in the past and in the future.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(ldt);

ZonedDateTime ldtZoned = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime utcZoned = ldtZoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC-3"));
System.out.println(utcZoned.toLocalDateTime());
```

It gives the output:

```
2020-02-03T20:55:33.313882
2020-02-03T17:55:33.313882
```